# How to display in Java jTextField the data from Arduino RFID

Tags: java, serial-port, rfid

I have this problem in my system where when I scan the card on RFID, it displays the UID using `System.out.println(str);` but when I passed it thru `jTextField.setText(str);`, it doesn't display the UID. Also, the weird part is, when i try to `System.out.println(jTextField.getText());` it display the UID.

Can someone help me with this problem? And explain if possible why does it happen?

This is my main class:

```
public class IDSystem {

  public static String devicePortName = "Arduino Uno";
  public static SerialPort arduinoPort = null;
  public static InputStream arduinoStream = null;
  public static int PACKET_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 8;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int len = SerialPort.getCommPorts().length;
    SerialPort serialPorts[] = new SerialPort[len];
    serialPorts = SerialPort.getCommPorts();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

      String portName = serialPorts[i].getDescriptivePortName();
      if (portName.contains(devicePortName)) {
        arduinoPort = serialPorts[i];
        arduinoPort.openPort();
        break;
      }
    }

    PacketListener listener = new PacketListener();
    arduinoPort.addDataListener(listener);

    Login l = new Login();
    l.setVisible(true);
 }

}
```

This is my `PacketListener` class:

```
public final class PacketListener implements SerialPortPacketListener {

  String ex = "/";
  String id;

  @Override
  public int getPacketSize() {
    return IDSystem.PACKET_SIZE_IN_BYTES;
  }

  @Override
  public int getListeningEvents() {
    return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;
  }

  @Override
  public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

    byte[] newData = event.getReceivedData();
    String str = new String(newData).split("\n", 2)[0].replaceAll("\\s+", "");

    int byteSize = 0;
    try {
        byteSize = str.getBytes("UTF-8").length;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PacketListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    if (byteSize == IDSystem.PACKET_SIZE_IN_BYTES) {

        System.out.println(str);
        Login l = new Login();
        l.jTextField.setText(l.jTextField.getText() + str);
        System.out.println(l.jTextField.getText());
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: There is something I don't get about your code: What is "Login"? Is it a JFrame or a JDialog? Also, try using just l.jTextField.setText(str); Besides, I think that you forgot to call "l.setVisible(true)"

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your jtextfield is an instance of javax.swing.JTextField.

If it doesn't display the text you specified, check that:

- You are setting the text on the correct JTextField instance,
- You are adding the correct JTextField instance to a container (JPanel, etc...) that is being displayed.
- As a last resort, if it's because you added the JTextField instance to its container after the container was already showing on the screen, try container.validate(); container.repaint(); .

If you could show the code for your Login class and how your jtextfield is being added to a container and displayed on the screen that would help in diagnosing the problem.